# Activity Process

Tags: android

I have 4 activities. A,B,C and D.

From each activity user can start any activity.
i.e. Activity A has 3 buttons to start B,C and D. In same way all other activities also has 3 buttons.

Now my question is If user go in this sequence A->B->C->B.Now If user press back button then this sequence happens.  B->C->->B->A. I want to change in this way B->->C->A. how can i do this?

Comment: Screen is not properly designed. **Do you think its well-designed navigation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't clearly understand your question, but maybe try use:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

You want to keep the same instance all the time, not create a new one, yes?

Answer (score 0):

finish activity B using finish() when you moved in the forward direction that means A>B(finish())>C>B

Comment: but what heppen if he return from c

Comment: you will be directed to Activity A

Comment: I answered this but this is not the way to implement navigation for a good app.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Krishnakant said you need to add finish(); everytime, As far as I'm aware the back button is called as the Achille's heel for android programming as coding or adding handlers to it is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);` before staring any activity.